# Can't install NVIDIA driver even after stoping lightdm

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lightdm, gpu-driver

I want to install NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.59.run using command
from tty1

```
sudo su

sudo service lightdm stop
```

that generate output

```
Stop : Unknown Instance:
```

then continue with

```
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.59.run
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.59.run
```

But I can't install and they said I must closed the X Server.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. Any idea?
thanks

Comment: Why use that .run? any reason? Just use this command `sudo apt-get install nvidia-346` and it will install without issue.

Answer (score 0):

The correct command to stop lightdm is:

```
sudo stop lightdm
```

But it is a really bad idea to install drivers this way.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try to change your runlevel with the  command telinit:

```
telinit 3
```

Here is an extract of the man page of runlevel which describes the different runlevels:

```
   ┌─────────┬───────────────────┐
   │Runlevel │ Target            │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │0        │ poweroff.target   │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │1        │ rescue.target     │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │2, 3, 4  │ multi-user.target │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │5        │ graphical.target  │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │6        │ reboot.target     │
   └─────────┴───────────────────┘
```